# Which video player pauses when I press on the screen?

Tags: video

Is there a video player for Ubuntu that I can pause and play the video by pressing any area on screen like in qq player for Windows? (if you understand what I mean)

Comment: Isn't it more convenient to just press Space? That works on any player. Nevertheless, IIRC you can pause with a click with VLC.

Comment: thank you ,it is the first time to know that I can pause by space ,thanks again

Comment: I hardly can think of an Ubuntu video player that **doesn't** have this option, excepting VLC, unless the plugin mentioned in the answer is installed.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to install [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) and the [VLC pause click plugin](https://github.com/nurupo/vlc-pause-click-plugin). 
To install VLC :

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

- remove snap installation of vlc (if exists)
- install vlc:

  sudo apt-get install vlc
- install dependencies:

  sudo apt-get install build-essential pkg-config libvlccore-dev libvlc-dev
- download, extract zip: https://github.com/nurupo/vlc-pause-click-plugin
- install plugin from the extracted folder:

  make
  sudo make install
- configure vlc, see section: 
  https://github.com/nurupo/vlc-pause-click-plugin#usage